# Best approach with arrowKt and repositories

Tags: kotlin, software-design, arrow-kt

I have an usecase on my work and I want to discuss with you what should be the best approach to do it.

In repository functions that should finds only one line what should be the best approach, return left when entity is not found on database or return right null.

WHat do you think about it?

I tried to find some consistent answer to this question but could not find it.
Imho the left behavior should be the best as the most cases on code you expect to find the entity on database to continue your function, so return null will cause to have null checks every time.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of approaches you can take here, but nullable is certainly a fair option and there are idiomatic ways to deal with `null` in Kotlin and Arrow.

Let's take an example, if you're already working with `Either`, or typed errors, than I personally prefer to use *domain specific errors*. Since I try to always follow DDD.

`EntityNotFound` is often not more descriptive than `null` but `UserNotFound` or `ArticleNotFound` is much more precise about what went wrong. So if you DDD then I would recommend modelling your errors precisely like that.

```kotlin
sealed interface UserError
data class UserNotFound(val uuid: UUID): UserError
data class UserAlreadyExists(val username: String): UserError

data class User(val uuid: UUID)

interface UserPersistence {
  suspend fun insert(user: User): Either<UserAlreadyExists, UUID>
  suspend fun fetch(user: UUID): Either<UserNotFound, User>
}
```

Alternatively you could user `User?` instead of `Either<UserNotFound, User>` and use `ensureNotNull` inside `either` to achieve the same behavior.

```kotlin
interface UserPersistence {
  suspend fun insert(user: User): Either<UserAlreadyExists, UUID>
  suspend fun fetchOrNull(user: UUID): User?

  suspend fun fetch(uuid: UUID): Either<UserNotFound, User> =
    either { ensureNotNull(fetchOrNull(uuid)) { UserNotFound(uuid) }
}
```

This shows that the two can easily be converted between each-other. `ensureNotNull` also applies smart-casting on the value passed to it, similar to `kotlin.requireNotNull` of `if(value != null)` so you get all the goodies from the Kotlin language as well.

You can find a full example of a repository layer here, https://github.com/nomisRev/ktor-arrow-example/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/io/github/nomisrev/repo/UserPersistence.kt